# Connection reset when running Jupyterhub with Docker

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I'm trying to run Jupyterhub in a Docker container (see [this link](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/)). I run the command listed under "Docker" and the container successfully runs but when I go to connect at http://localhost:8000, I get a message saying "The connection was reset."
I have also tried creating a Dockerfile that makes use of `jupyterhub/configurable-http-proxy` because I thought that might have been what was missing but I couldn't connect with that either. Additionally I tried adding a `jupyterhub_config.py` to the container with no luck.
Is there a step I am missing or something else that I need to configure to get Jupyterhub running in a Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a short-lived bug in version 0.9. Pulling a newer version using

`docker pull jupyterhub/jupyterhub`

solved this issue.